# Turn OFF the white flash WITH 10.8.5 - the old solution is no longer an option

Tags: macos, error

I have ALREADY tried:

1. Within the System Preferences/Accessibility:  De-Select Flash the
   screen when an alert appears.
2. Toggling Select then back to De-Select
3. While I found the solution to delete: 
   ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.universalaccess.plist - 10.8.5
   replaced Universal Access with "Accessibility", which has no
   apparent equivalent file within the Lib/prefs.  If there IS, please
   let me know.

I really hate the white flash.  REALLY hate it.

BTW: I did do my own research before asking this question, including on this AskDifferent website.  The solution found on AskDifferent and other sites only work on older Mac systems (up to ~ 2011).  The ones with UniversalAccess.

Thanks, in advance for any useful input.
- Scott

Answer (score 1):

The plist you listed is the correct one to remove. Remove it and try rebooting, and your problem should be resolved. If not, create a new user account and log into it, and see if the problem persists.